# How to check if variable is not falsy but 0 passes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables, truthy, falsy

Is there an elegant way to check if variable is NOT falsy but in case of 0 it passes. The issue with this way of verifying
`if(var !== undefined && var !== null)`
is that it's long and doesn't cover all cases like `undecalred` or `NaN`. I'm also using typescript and declare it as optional number.

Comment: If you just have `number?` in TS, then you don't need to check *all* falsy values, you just need to check for `undefined` and maybe `NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do exactly what your first sentence asks:

```
if (!x && x !== 0)
```

means literally "if x is falsy and x is not 0".

Also the `==` and `!=` comparison operators explicitly consider `null` and `undefined` to be equal, so

```
if (x != null)
```

is `true` for both `null` and `undefined`. (That's `!=`, not `!==`.)

Comment: will `(x != null)` consider cases like `undeclared` or `NaN`?

Comment: @valentinIvanov undeclared variables will always throw an error if you try to read them. With that said you *should **not*** have undeclared variables. There is a serious problem with the code if a variable might exist or not at some point. You should have reliable code.

Comment: @valentinIvanov as for `NaN` - no `NaN != null` is `true`. Only `undefined` and `null` are loosely equal to each other https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @valentinIvanov The `==` and `!=` rules consider `null` and `undefined` to be the same, but only those two falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Check(input) {
   if (!input && input!==0){
    return "falsy";   
   }
   else if (input === 0){
    return "zero";
   
   }
   
}
console.log(Check(0));
console.log(Check(false))
```